# How to pass jquery array/object to function that expects a MS Ajax object

Tags: javascript, jquery, microsoft-ajax

I've a big project where there still exist some MS ajax functions used all over the project. I could rewrite them using jquery but for now that would take to much time.

However we now using jquery for every new functionality.

Take a look at this:

```
    $.each($("a[xonclick]"), function (index, value) {
            EnableButton(value);
        });
    function EnableButton(btn) {
        ...
        var xonclick = btn.getAttribute("xonclick");
        ...
    }
```

Off course i get the javascript error:

```
getAttribute is not a function
```

I know i could use `btn.attr("xonclick");` but that's not an option as i mentioned before.

Is there some jquery function that gives me a MS ajax object for a jquery object? I could then use that object and pass it to the enableButton function.

UPDATE: JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/wsYCJ/1/

I hope i explained it well and someone of you knows a solution for this.

Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you're asking. `$.each($("a[xonclick]"))` (as well as `$("a[xonclick]").each()`) will feed DOM elements to `EnableButton()`, and DOM elements do support the `getAttribute()` method. I also don't know how AJAX would relate to your question...

Comment: Hello, the $get(id) is a member of the Microsoft Ajax client library (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383788.aspx) I'll create a fiddle to demonstrate. thanks

Comment: Yup, I know `$get()` is part of ASP.NET AJAX, but I cannot find such a call in your question. Did you end up posting the code you actually wanted to post? :)

Comment: Hi, on all other places i use something like this: EnableButton($get('myId')); And the the getAttribute Function is working. But when i pass the jquery object, it fails.. I've updated my question with a fiddle showing the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you said in the comments, [$get()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397717) is part of the ASP.NET AJAX library and returns an augmented DOM element (actually an instance of [Sys.UI.DomElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383788.aspx)).

On the other hand, jQuery's [$()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/) function returns a jQuery object that wraps one or more DOM elements. jQuery objects do not support `getAttribute()`, DOM elements do.

You can use [get()](http://api.jquery.com/get/) or the indexer syntax to get an actual DOM element from a jQuery object. In other words, you have to write:

```
function buttonClicked() {
     getAttr($("#test")[0]);
}
```

Instead of:

```
function buttonClicked() {
     getAttr($("#test"));
}
```

You will find an updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/wsYCJ/2/).

Comment: Hello, this will indeed fix the fiddle :) But.. when using jquery each function will pass already a single domElement. I don't know what i did wrong before, but this fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/wsYCJ/3/) with "each" works now correctly using getAttribute. Thanks for your help, you finally encouraged me to try getAttribute again :)